# Ordering posts by distance to city using geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am trying to order my posts by how close they are to the location of the current user using geocoder. 
Here is the controller:

```
def top
@city = request.location.city
@closepost = Post.near(@city, order: :distance)
end
```

and here is the view:

```
<% @closepost.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_f' for {:order=>:distance}:Hash
```

Comment: shouldn't @closepost be plural in controller?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake i changed that. Now getting undefined method `to_f' for {:order=>:distance}:Hash error.  Sensing @closepost line is wrong but don't know what to change it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller you define:

`@closepost`

while in view you are calling:

`@closeposts`

and you call `.each` on a variable that is not defined.

**update**

```
irb> a=Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode '140 Market St, San Francisco, CA' 
irb> a.ll 
=> 37.79363,-122.396116

@closeposts = Post.within(5, :origin => @city.ll).order('distance DESC')
```

**with geocode**

```
@closeposts = Post.near('dublin', 50, :order => :distance)
```

You missed the distance parameter

Comment: Oops my bad. Now i am getting that undefined method `to_f' for {:order=>:distance}:Hash error.

Comment: where exactly have you found this `.near(@city, order: :distance)` method? I was looking in the docs and couldn't find something for `order`.

Comment: Found from another stackoverflow answer so i don't even know if its correct. I couldnt find anything in the docs to sort by distance from ip location.

Comment: looks wrong to me, you'll need to add `geokit-rails gem` https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails and use `Location.within(5, :origin => @somewhere).order('distance DESC, nbr_seats ASC')`

Comment: `@closepost = Post.within(5, :origin => @city).order('distance DESC')`

Comment: Error uninitialized constant PostsController::Geocoders on this line: @city = Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(:geo_location). I think this is how you find ip location so your line will work.

Comment: Actually city must represent an array of data as long and lat, in my app I had  `@location = Location.find (params[:id])`  where location had long and lat attributes with data saved on Location create, so in my  case  I would have `@locations = Location.within(5, :origin => @location).order('distance DESC') ` and geokit rails will use lat and long attributes for this  so that in other form the code  could be written as `@locations= Location.within(5, :origin => [56.8766778, 987.7657778]).order('distance DESC') `  where the numbers in array are  values of lat and long.

Comment: Ah ok I get it. Instead of having a set location do you know how i would find the long and lat of the users ip address?

Comment: In your controller you are finding the city by ip, after this you need to get this city long and lat  values and this should be it

Comment: On a mobile device now and it makes hard to look for documentations to help you now

Comment: Ok but @city = request.location.city was for Geocoder gem. Will this stay the same geokit?

Comment: Right, you'll probably need to use geokit gem and geokit rails,depends on your app needs, all my suggestions until now were for geokit and geokit rails

Comment: With geocode -  @closeposts = Post.near(@city, 50, :order => :distance)   - in your code the distance is missing(range), found here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

Comment: So close. SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.distance. Does this just mean make a post column distance:integer?